# I've created a private blockchain with geth and curious if this ether is real and spendable?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, network, private

I have a small private network which generates roughly 20,000 ether daily.. I read of this private network configuration often and it seams like people are actually using this Ether as real ether that is tradable for Bitcoin.. Although I'm successfully creating and sending translations which I've tested sending to my coinable.com account and my MyEtherWallet.com account.. neither seem to receive my private network generated ether.. Am I chasing a dream? Or doing something wrong.. Please help I've either wisely invested months of research or wasted a LOT of time and ruined my relationship with my wife in the process... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. It's not possible.

On the real ethereum network you're just some random account with no actual funds trying to pass bad cheques. It won't work.

Hope it helps.